# How to detect one 3D mesh part contained within the other 3D mesh part

Tags: 3d, game-engine, mesh

I need to detect if one part contains another part.

Imagine a shape such as closed Mail Box with some small holes in it. This Mail Box shape contains a Tea Pot inside. What would be an approach to detect that Tea Pot 3D mesh object is contained within closed Mail Box 3D mesh object. I cannot remove Tea Pot from closed Mail Box with only small holes in it. This is opposite to Open Mail Box. I can easily remove Tea Pot from open Mail Box object.

Comment: How much knowledge do you have ? How do you handle the "opening the door" case ? If you have an articulation to rotate around to open the door you could estimate if the angle is large enough to let the teapot go using simple maths.

Comment: Tea Pot and Mail Box is just the example. I am looking for generic algorithm that would take two meshes and give answer if one mesh contained in another and you cant really remove it from the containing mesh. I think the only approach i see for now is some kind of Path Finding algorithm to try to find an "exit path" for the Tea Pot mesh out of Mail Box mesh. But i already can see it is going to be very computationally expensive. Also no idea where to even start with that.

Comment: Maybe try looking at CSPs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), it's used to solve some problems in robotics, maybe you can find something suitable for you there

Comment: You can always do a ray-casting from the tea pot. If any of the projected rays don't intersect with the mail box, it must not be enclosed.

Comment: That is why my question mentions that box has small air holes. Ray casting may accidentally detect those as box being open even though it is closed

Comment: I've previously gotten good results by just adding a threshold to how many rays are allowed to escape. e.g., a mesh is considered to be enclosed if fewer than 5% of the rays go off to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you might want to start more coarsely. For example, you should be able to determine if the bounding box of the teapot is within the bounding box of the mailbox. If you need more fine-grained tests for other objects, you can then go to the convex hulls of the 2 objects and test whether one is within the other.

Comment: bounding boxes cannot help distinguish "open mail box" and "closed mail box" cases. Convex Hull also useless in this case.

Comment: If you’re drawing the mailbox you know whether it’s open or not because you drew it that way.